# Complete scoped model async call in initstate before widget builds

Tags: flutter, scoped-model

I have a requirement which is to make an API call when the page is opened and use the result of the API call to populate a widget. I have to cater for cases like when the call is being made, show a loader, if an error occurs, show a widget that allows the user to reload the page which calls that method again if the call is successful use the result to populate the widget. 
This looks like a perfect use case for a FutureBuilder, however, should the call fail, there won't be a way to reload as FutureBuilder is executed once. 
An alternative is to use a StreamBuilder where I just add to the stream the error or response, this allows me to reload the page if the call fails. The streambuidler approach works fine.

Initially, I've tried to use a ScopedModel approach by making the async API call in the initstate method, however, as expected the api call takes some time and the widget Build method is called so the page is built before the api call completes and when it's done, even if I call notifylisteners() the widget tree doesn't rebuild with the data from the API call. Is there a way to make this work using a ScopedModel approach?

```
DashboardService.dart

      Future<string> getDashboardState() async{
    try{
        var response = await client.get('/getdashboardstate');
        return response;    
    }catch(error){
      return error;
    }
    }



DashboardModel.dart
    Future<BaseDataResponse<MambuLoan>> getDashboardState() async {
    try {
      setState(ViewState.Busy);
      var info = await _dashboardService.getDashboardState();
      if (info.isSuccessful) {
        return info;
      } else {
          setState(ViewState.Error);
          return info;
      }
    } catch (error) {
        setState(ViewState.Error);
       return error;
    }
  }

DashboardView.dart

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getDashboard() // result of this set some data in the scopedmodel
  }

Future<String> getDashboard() async{
   var response = await dashboardModel.getDashboardState();
   return response;
}

Widget Build(BuildContext context){
  //gets data in scoped model to build widget
  return Container() //actual widget here
}
```

**UPDATE**

I Was approaching this the wrong way. I ended up not needing a stateful widget but a stateless one in which I called my Future in the build method before returning a widget.

Comment: use `FutureBuilder` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: @AaronSaunders I already mentioned in my question that I'd tried FutureBuilder which works but wouldn't work with retrying if the call fails. StreamBuilder works better but I'm trying to make it work with scopedmodel.

Comment: The widget should redraw on error if you update the state... when the widget redraws it will execute the Future again... I believe. See this medium post - https://medium.com/flutterpub/network-call-with-progress-error-retry-in-flutter-8b58585f0b26

Comment: @AaronSaunders Thanks the article helped. I solved this by not using a stateful widget and then calling my future in the build method of the widget and then on error  user taps a button which calls the future again in which notifyListeners() is called which then triggers a rebuild.